# How can I use c# asp.net to get data from url?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to get some info I sent by form to angularJS in my c# asp.net backend, and I'm having trouble doing it.

Visual Studio won't let me compile because it says:

> Error CS0120: an object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member'

That's is my controller

```
public class SearchController : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
        string test = HttpContext.Request.QueryString["txt_search"];
        return test;
    }

}
```

Here's what I got in my angularjs:

```
$scope.sendForm = function () {
    console.log($scope.model.search);
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/search?txt_search=' + $scope.model.search
    })
    .then(function () {
        console.log('sucesso a executar o post');
    }, function () {
           console.log('Erro ao executar o post');
       });
};
```

Comment: What does the network inspector say about the request in your browser? Also, it seems that you're asking how to use ASP.NET to _return_ data, not _get_ data? Or are you asking how to make a request _from_ C# to another website and then return that to your client?

Comment: I'm using to get data, but I'm returning just to check out if it is working out. Actually it's a search button which I need to filter my data in backend returning it to the front to show the user. Visual Studio won't let me compile because it says error CS0120: an object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member' @John

Comment: Can't you add an arument `string txt_search` to the Get method ? it should map automatically if the value is there in the URL.

Comment: can you please send me complete code? you must be using static method and accessing non static fields inside it

Comment: @ShanakaRusith It worked, thanks, but for some reason one of the requests returns with an error saying it was only http://localhost:63318/api/search, and 3 of then returns correctly with http://localhost:63318/api/search?txt_search=asd, why does it return 4 times and one of then does not use the ?txt_search thing?

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI sure, how do you want me to send it to you?

Comment: @ArthurPaiva It should be fine. if you don't pass a value to `txt_search`,  the `txt_search` should be null. Is this ASP.Core  ?

Comment: @Shanaka It doesn't seem to be (`ApiController`, not `Controller`)

Comment: Change `string txt_search` to `[FromQuery] string txt_search` and try agin

Comment: @ShanakaRusith it says fromquery atributte cant not be found diretive missing or assembly code

Comment: @Arthur It's because you're not using ASP.NET Core, in ASP.NET you need to use `[FromUri]`.

Comment: @ShanakaRusith I transformed from returning string to void and seems like its working out fine

Comment: @John which is the best way for me to use this txt_search variable in other controllers and methods outside? creating a class search with a static string which I instanciate every time?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you should just be able to change your method definition and skip this altogether:

```
public string Get(string txt_search)
{
    return txt_search;
}
```

Alternatively, to reference the current request, I believe you need to use the following (note the addition of `.Current`):

```
string test = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["txt_search"];
```

The reason is that `HttpContext` defines `Request` as an *instance* property. The only public *static* property is `Current`, which returns an instance of `HttpContext` through which you can reach `Request`.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow,

**Your Angular code is correct**

You need to pass a parameter on server side to collect `txt_search` value

Here it is:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/api/search")]
public string mySearchMethod(string txt_search)
{
    //something here with txt_search
    return "OK";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of the above solution will work, but for another approach as you are using asp.net web api and router you can make it as below as well

In your Angular code, simple pass the search as below

```

```
$scope.sendForm = function () {
    console.log($scope.model.search);
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/search/'+ $scope.model.search
    })
    .then(function () {
        console.log('sucesso a executar o post');
    }, function () {
           console.log('Erro ao executar o post');
       });
};
```

```

Notice 
`url: '/api/search/'+ $scope.model.search`

and change the Action method as below

```

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/api/search/{txt_search}")]
public string mySearchMethod(string txt_search)
{
    //something here with txt_search
    return "OK";
}
```

```

by doing this you don't have to worry about the name of the parameter `txt_search`
whatever you mention in route `[Route("/api/search/{txt_search}")]`, you will get the value in same parameter.